# ASP.NET Core fails to start in debug mode when SSL is enabled

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm getting the following error while launching debugger (F5) in Visual Studio:

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of WebApplication5.exe which is hosting your application. One or more errors occurred.

I've noticed that it happens when I set the applicationUrl (in launchSettings.json) to point to https url:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44399/",
    "sslPort": 44399
  }
```

}

It started happening after I upgraded .net code tools from RC2 to RTM.
Please help

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application on clean installed windows 10 + vs2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197265/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host)

Comment: Does running Visual Studio as Administrator help?

Comment: @Brad Tried "as Admin" before, it didn't help

Comment: @Set This is a very generic error. Another question is related to the previous versions (RC1) of asp.net core. I have a specific issue where it doesn't let me set https in applicationUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting a similar message. Try starting with CTRL+F5 (Debug > Start Without Debugging) and see if that gets you up and running. I still get a certificate error even though I've added a self-signed cert. Not sure what's up with that yet.

EDIT: For the sake of completeness I was able to reinstall the self-signed cert using these instructions:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/

Basically, once the site is up and running, go into Internet Explorer, click on the certificate error, and install from there.

Comment: Tried that before. Didn't help. For some reason, it doesn't like https in applicationUrl

Comment: Have you also tried creating a new project and copying over the config files? Check the global.json maybe?

Comment: Installing cert using Internet Explorer fixed the problem. (Ctrl+F5 wasn't enough)