# An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. One or more error occured

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have clone the project from source url. My friend has developed the asp.net core web application using .NetCore 1.0.0-preview2-003121 sdk. However on my pc I have install .NetCore 1.0.1-preview2-003131 sdk. **I am getting the error**. I changed the version in the global.json file as you can see below but still no solution.I google it but all the solution are not working for me.

Global.json file

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-FMM-02f339eb-4af7-42c9-b7f3-d05b48d36811",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "MailKit": "1.8.1",
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "xmlDoc": false
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "nlog.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Dot net version in my pc

How can I solve this issue. Please can anyone let me know about this.
[[image]

[[image]

Comment: What is the error message you get when you run `dotnet build` on the directory where the project is located (i.e., the directory where `project.json` is located)? Also, without knowing the error message you're getting... can you comment out `"sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131" }` from `global.json` and try as well?

Comment: @kimbaudi I comment the sdk same error. I have uploaded the error screen shots. Please have a look

Comment: I was hoping you can open your Command Prompt and `cd /d "D:\fish\FishermansMate\src\FMM"`. Then enter `dotnet build` and then `dotnet run`. Can you try? Based on your screenshot of Visual Studio Output, it looks like you have another process running dotnet, which means you might want to restart your PC and try running it again. That might solve your problem.

Comment: @kimbaudi - Same issue.... not working

Comment: try deleting the bin and obj folders. also try deleting project.lock.json. after that, restart Visual Studio and rebuild the project.

Comment: nothing working .... same issue.

Comment: @SanJaisy Are you unable to run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` in the command prompt from the project directory?

Comment: It is running fine ......

Comment: i am facing same error, any fix? see here for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/q/51747476/2089963

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old, but closing VS deleting my project.lock.json as @kimbaudi suggested worked for me

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. One or more errors occurred.

That problem can occur when three things are true:

1. your app is trying to run with SSL,
2. your app does not have an SSL Certificate setup, and
3. you are debugging your app (which is preventing SSL certificate setup).

**As a quick fix attempt**, run the app without debugging via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or view the app in the browser via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. That might install the SSL certificate for you. If it does not, consider changing your app's launch settings from HTTPS to HTTP. If you really need SSL, you'll have to figure out how to install and use an SSL certificate on your local machine.

Checkout out these on GitHub and StackOverflow.

- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1608
- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1723
- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/issues/17
- [An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application on clean installed windows 10 + vs2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197265/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host)

Comment: Any ideas what might cause this if the application is not using SSL?

Comment: I am getting this same Error, but not running in https, "Enable SSL" is off only, still getting this error, any pointers??

Answer (score 56):

Note that for IIS Express to work with SSL, the port needs to be in the **44300 through 44399 range** (from [How do I restore a missing IIS Express SSL Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate/38094929#38094929) -original article  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges)

For other ports Visual Studio 2017 didn't install the SSL Certificate, but I was able to install it as suggested  in  [How do I restore a missing IIS Express SSL Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate/38220369#38220369)

> From an elevated command prompt run (specify your port number):

```
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
    IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:55555/ -UseSelfSigned
```

**Edit:**

Then browse to the website https://localhost:44348/ (using FF) and if you're prompted add the security exception.

Comment: that one helped me. Changing the port sorted the problem out. Thank you.

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: You are absolutely right, was using 43301 instead of 44301

Comment: Saved me amount of time

Answer (score 35):

This may happen when you try to run your application with the "Enable SSL" setting enabled, and if the self-signed certificate has not been installed as a trusted root certificate.

To fix, follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> to start your application and have VS create the self-signed certificate.
2. If the application did not start in Internet Explorer, open an IE window and copy/paste the start URL into that window.
3. IE will display a certificate warning. Click "Continue to this website."
4. Click on the red certificate error symbol in the address bar and then "View certificates".
5. In the dialog that opens click "Install certificate...".
6. In the certification installation dialog choose "Local machine", (not "Current user"), then click "Next".
7. Select "Place all certificates into the following store" and in the "Browse..." dialog, select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".
8. Complete the installation dialog, then close and reopen the browser tab. Now no certificate error should be displayed.

You are all set now to run your project with <kbd>F5</kbd> in debug mode.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue, eventually realizing that I had set up an HTTPS URL Rewrite in my application's web.config for use in production.  However, I didn't want to mess with SSL in my dev environment, so I decided to remove it.

After deleting the  section and attempting to debug the app again, I noticed that Chrome kept redirecting my localhost to HTTPS, in spite of the fact that I hadn't selected "Enable SSL" in the application properties.

**What finally got my app debugging locally in HTTP again was clearing my Chrome cache.**

Hope this helps someone else who's stuck!

Comment: The redirection from HTTP to HTTP could most likely because of the HSTS settings. Type in Chrome's address bar the following and press enter
chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Answer (score 2):

Please remember always to declare your new IIS Web Site in hosts file inside System32 folder if you are using Windows. This was my case, feeling dump!

Answer (score 2):

by adding in .csproj file in PropertyGroup solved this issue for me

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Comment: After changing from OutOfProcess to InProcess the problem was solved for us.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem arised because of redirect rule in web.config (http -> https). Try to disable redirect rule and check if it works.

Comment: I had to remove both `httpRedirect` and `rewrite` sections

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error. In my case I overlooked the fact that I had URL Re-Write rules in my web.config file (doh). Commenting out the re-write rule fixed the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to Https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a .NET Core app and I had accidentally changed my IIS settings *launchSettings.json* to use https instead of http. Reverting that change automatically fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I fixed this error by changing the **Hosting Model as In Process**.
Please go in the startup solution's properties area and change it to In Process and then try.
In my case, it was not fixed by deleting bin and obj several times but changing this hosting model fixed issue at my end.
Please follow this screen shot :

[image]

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS (not Express) a simple Stop and Start of it did the work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following steps:

- Copying the appsettings.Development.json from the Solution folder to \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
- Rename it to appsettings.json

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing:

CMD:

netsh
http
add iplisten ipaddress=192.168.xxx.xxx

then control + c to exist,
then
iisreset

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and what i did to fix was in my launchSettings.json I added this line of code and do not change the http to https or you will get the same error

"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:add your localhost Id",
      "sslPort": 44342
    }

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure your IP address hasn't changed (if using a DNS name)

Whether using 'real DNS' or an override in `hosts` make sure your local IP hasn't changed.

If you're using NAT and you don't have a fixed local IP assigned to your machine this is very easy to do. In fact it could be months before you are issued with a new IP making it all the more confusing!

I had an entry

`192.168.1.134    dev.example.com`

in my hosts file, but my local IP changed to `192.168.1.136`.

You can probably use `127.0.0.1` instead.

After fixing this for my case I had to restart Visual Studio, and also full IIS (not sure why).

PS. I actually set `192.168.1.134` in my 'real DNS' to facilitate testing on mobile devices with a proper DNS name and certificate. So when this changes it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you don't have a proxy enabled for LAN**

Other answers are great but I got this error after a restart following a crash. 
When Windows crashed it was running Fiddler, which registers itself as a LAN proxy. 
Fiddler cannot unregister itself due to crash and when windows boots browsers etc work but LAN proxy setting is now messing up access to IIS Express (would probably mess with IIS too)

So make sure you don't have a local proxy configured in your Internet options

Answer (score 0):

I could not get IIS Express to run using HTTPS, but I was able to make it work using the 'webApp' profile (launch as project). From command line, I had to run:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

--trust is optional but will prevent browser warnings for an untrusted cert.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue tried almost all solutions mentioned here but then eventually found that I have an error in error list after resolving the issue I was able to run my project.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing Shaun Luttin correct answer I found my issue.

I had rewrite rules in the web.config which I forgot to comment out when debugging, and then uncomment it when deploying to 'auto' redirect to HTTPS always.

(MVC Core 3.1 with web.config)

Following was the issue:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was not using SSL so the cause was most likely something else. For me it worked if I ran Visual Studio as an administrator.